# Automatic download/upload

Tags: client-server

We are going to develop a client-server application with web interface which will store office documents on server.

When we use browser as a client we need to perform these three steps to edit a document:

1. download document to the local machine;
2. open it in office program and edit;
3. upload document to the server.

It is very inconvenient. Sometimes it is hard to find where a document was downloaded to, when we need to upload it. Customers will also forget to upload document after editing.

Is there any way or technology to upload document automatically?

Or just any ideas how to make this process more convenient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean like Sharepoint does with office documents?

Answer (score 0):

I would, suggest, **if applicable** to store all documents as HTML then allowing editing in a web page powered by [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or a similar tool.

If your documents **must** be in another format, like Office formats, you might start thinking at Office 365, or use ActiveX controls in your web application, something I believe should be deprecated but works in small (better *restricted*) enterprise environments.

These are just a couple of ideas.